# Two buttons using hook in Woocommerce MyAccount - Order View Page

Tags: button, woocommerce, hook

I'm trying to add two buttons to Woocommerce / MyAccount / View Order Details (Not in orders list) (ORDER AGAIN | CANCEL) but I only see the 'Order Again' in completed orders but not in other statuses. Thank you!

```html
function cs_add_order_again_to_my_orders_details( $actions, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( array( 'completed','pending', 'processing', 'on-hold', 'failed' ) ) ) {
        $actions['order-again'] = array(
            'url'  => wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( 'order_again', $order->id ) , 'woocommerce-order_again' ),
            'name' => __( 'Order Again', 'woocommerce' )
        );
      
      // cancel button
        $actions['cancel'] = array(
        'url' => NO_IDEA,
        'name' => NO_IDEA
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_details', 'cs_add_order_again_to_my_orders_details', 50, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, only orders with `completed` status can be reordered. You can add other statuses with the following hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_order_again', 'ywp_filter_order_again' );
function ywp_filter_order_again( $statuses ) {
    return array( 'completed', 'pending', 'processing', 'on-hold', 'failed' );
}
```

And for cancel order button:

```
    $actions['cancel'] = array(
        'url' => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
        'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
```

By default, only orders with pending status can be canceled. You can add other situations with the following hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', 'ywp_filter_cancel_order' );
function ywp_filter_cancel_order( $statuses ) {
        return array( 'completed', 'pending', 'processing', 'on-hold', 'failed' );
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much Hamid, it works perfectly, I can re-order now from any status. First part is solved.